ReactJS push into an array
Hi im trying to learn react by doing a simple block notes.
import React from 'react';
import './style.css'
import { Tnote } from '../../types.ts/commonTypes';

interface anyProps {
    data: Tnote[]
    onSelectedNote: (note: Tnote) => void
}

function Aside(props: anyProps) {

return (
    <div className='notesname'>
        <div>
            {props.data.map((item)=>
            <div key={item.id} className='nota' onClick={()=> props.onSelectedNote(item)}>{item.titolo}</div>)}
        </div>
        <button className='newnote'>Nuova Nota</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Aside;

This is my aside component i want that when i click on the button "newnote" the text from textArea is pushed into an array how can i do this
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './style1.css'
import { Tnote } from '../../types.ts/commonTypes';



function Textarea(props:{
    nota: Tnote | null
}) {

  const [text, setText] = useState(props.nota?.contenuto || "") 
  const [title, setTitle] =useState(props.nota?.titolo || "")

  
   useEffect(() => {
      setText(props.nota?.contenuto || "")
      setTitle(props.nota?.titolo || "")
  }, [props.nota])


return (
  <div className='titlecont'>
    <textarea placeholder='Inserici il titolo della tua nota' id='title' value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}></textarea>
    <textarea placeholder='Inserisci il testo della tua nota..' id='content' value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}></textarea>
  </div>
  );
}

export default Textarea;

This is my textArea
Any tips and advice are accepted since i really want to learn React
I tried a simple onClick on the button but it didn't work

The two components you've provided don't have any direct relation as it is. It isn't clear what you actually want to do. Pushing into an array in React is the same as you would do in javascript. You don't have an array state variable, which is the only time you may need to interact with an array differently than you normally would. You'll have to be a bit more specific about what your array is and how you've tried to push to it.
